# ASP.NET MVC HTTPS Redirect without exposing authentication information

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, https

I have a site for which I must force HTTPS everywhere.

I am concerned that in doing the HTTP to HTTPS redirect, if a user is already logged in (via cookies or tokens), that authentication information may be transferred inadvertedently in clear text.

How can I ensure that this does not happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to safely do a redirect without secure information being captured is with the rewrite engine - assuming you have no token/secure information in the URL itself (ie: session, etc).

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

If you analyze the results of this configuration in Fiddler, you'll notice that the initial non-secured request has no secured information even if the user is authenticated.

Here is the GET request:

```
GET http://www.someurl.net/Dashboard HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: www.someurl.net
```

The response is just a standard 301 perm redirect again with nothing secured transferred:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 13:07:53 GMT
Location: https://www.someurl.net/Dashboard
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive

<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://www.someurl.net/Dashboard">here</a></body>
```

Comment: What about the HTTP headers?

Comment: Also, how might this be done without relying on the rewrite module?

Comment: You could probably do a check in the `Application_BeginRequest` event of the global.asax or possibly even create an MVC filter. As for HTTP headers, the GET request is the full GET request I captured on one of my dev sites after I was logged in, and then requested a locked down page. That is all that is sent as part of the request unsecured.